# charts.PerformanceSummary colours

Tags: r, xts, performanceanalytics

I would like to use a colour palate for `charts.PerformanceSummary` in the `PerformanceAnalytics` package, but for some reason it is not displaying all three graphs.

Below is a reproducible example.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
n <- 12
d <- 1000
v <- xts(matrix(rnorm(n*d,0.0001,0.003),ncol=n),Sys.Date()-c(1:d))
colnames(v) <- LETTERS[1:n]
charts.PerformanceSummary(v,col=rainbow12equal)

Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  formal argument "col" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you should set `colorset` not `col`:

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(v,colorset=rainbow12equal)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Knew it was simple